# Continuity of Two Functions: Partial Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Show that if $f$ is a continuously differentiable real-valued function on an open interval in $E^2$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \, \partial y}= 0,$ then there are continuously differentiable real-valued functions $f_1, f_2$ on open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=f_1(x)+f_2(y).$

I know there's this lemma in my book (Maxwell Rosenlicht) that says: Let $f$ be a real-valued function on an open subset $U$ of $E^n$ and let $a \in U$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there exist real-valued functions $A_1, \ldots,A_n$ on $U$, continuous at $a$, such that
$f(x)-f(a)=A_1(x)(x_1-a_l)+A_2(x)(x_2-a_2)+ \ldots+A_n(x)(x_n-a_n).$
that I should use, but I don't know how to start with this, could you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by noting that

$\int \dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \, \partial y}dy=$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=g(x)$ because $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \, \partial y}=0$.

Then, $f(x,y)=\int g(x)dx=G(x)+\alpha (y)$ where $\alpha (y)$ is the constant of integration w.r.t $x$.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail, please?

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: Could you show me how this could be done using the lemma?